# nodemailer html message strips the text from fs reader

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs, nodemailer

I am reading a text file content like this:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' +'/myfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        mycontent = data
        console.log("print here:",mycontent)
    })
```

and then I pass it to the nodemailer as the html message :

```
var mailMessage = '<p>' + mycontent + '</p>';
```

but when the email is sent, the content of the text file loses its line breaks in the email message.
How can I preserve it?

original text content:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde 
omnis iste natus error sit 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
laudantium, totam rem aperiam, 
eaque ipsa quae ab illo 
inventore veritatis
```

current outcome is like:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
```

the purpose is to perseve the original line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTML will be parsed without taking notice of line breaks. You could recognise these line breaks in your javascript, and replace them with a `<br/>`, for example.

try this:

```
var mailMessage = '<p>' + mycontent.split("\n").join("<br/>") + '</p>';
```

Comment: so how should I do it then? could please suggest a solution?

Comment: I edited my answer with a proposed solution - try it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readFile(__dirname +'/' +'/myfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        mycontent = data.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
        console.log("print here:",mycontent)
    })
```

you can simply edit it when you get it from the file.